# Python for print last value of each if statement

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I'm doing a for loop in python, but I don't know how to print the last value accumulated within each branch of the `if` statement... i.e. (not for each iteration of the loop):

```
a = 0
for i in range(0,10):
    if i<2:
        a+= i
    elif i>7:
        a+= i
print a
```

The first branch increments `a` to 0 and 1, so I want to print "1". The second branch has also increments `a` twice, to 9 and 18, so I want to print "18".

Current Output

```
18
```

Expected output

```
1
18
```

Comment: Are you sure about that edit OP? Your question makes no sense at all now.

Comment: Please re-read your whole question and fix it.

Comment: You still have this: "but I want it to print first 0 then 9"

Comment: Please fix your question.

Comment: sorry, forgot to edit that

Comment: Also, please take the time to explain in detail what is special about 1, 18 vs 0, 17. Don't leave that in the comments because your question is impossible to understand without that information.

Comment: the first if has two outputs, 0 and 1, I want the "1", the second if has also two outputs, 17 and 18, I want the "18"... in both cases I want the last output

Comment: In the question please. I already read your previous comment. Questions should be standalone. People should be able to answer them without having to read your comments.

Comment: Let me know if my answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: Close vote retracted. Thanks for being responsive despite the original intent being very unclear.

Comment: you are right, the example is so simple that it has infinite answers, I will post the real command, thanks

Comment: Updated my answer with a much shorter solution.

Comment: I hope you like my edits. I think I made it pretty unambiguous without needing a more complicated example.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,10):
    if (i < 1) or (i > 8):
        print i
```

Produces:

```
0
9
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by @gilgameshbk just indent the `print a` statement. Python unlike other languages like c or Java is sensitive to indentation. Your code should look like this -

```
a=0
for i in range(0,10):
    if i<1 or i>8 :
        a+=i
        print a
```

The problem was that your `print` statement was out of the `if` blocks.Note that you should have used `or` to make the code more compact.

Comment: You really don't need those parens around the condition in the `if`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes. It was a mistake. I had started my computer learning from c. So I tend to think in C. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have clarified your intent somewhat, it looks like you are trying to increment for every element in certain ranges, then print the last element for that range.

For the trivial example that you show, do

```
a = 0
for i in range(10):
    if i < 2:
        a += i
        if i == 1:
            print(a)
    elif i > 7:
        a += i
        if i == 9:
            print(a)
```

In a more general sense, it you can use the fact that you really have multiple ranges here and that [range objects are indexable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range).

In your example, you have two ranges:

```
ranges = [range(2), range(7, 10)]
```

You can loop over them, do the incrementing and print on the last element of each range:

```
a = 0
for rng in ranges:
    for i in rng:
        a += i
        if i == rng[-1]:
            print(a)
```

In fact, you don't really need the inner loop at all since `range` objects can be passed directly to `sum`:

```
for rng in ranges:
    a += sum(rng)
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print the total sum only, I suggest you use `list` comprehensions like this:

```
result = [sum(x for x in range(0,10) if x < 2), sum(y for y in range(0,10) if y >7 or y < 2)]
for i in result:
    print i
```

output:

```
1
18
```

if you want to use `if-`statements instead, you can use a `boolean` to check if the low value is printed or not like:

```
a = 0
printed = False
for i in range(0,10):
    if i<2:
        a+= i
    elif i>7:
        if not printed:
            print a
            printed = True
        a+= i
print a
```

output:

```
1
18
```

Comment: The question has been clarified significantly. This is not what OP is looking for.

Comment: @MadPhysicist this is because the question was edited more than 3 times with 3 different expected results

Comment: The result you showed originally was not a valid option for any of them. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: Also, `a=result[-1]` probably

Answer (score -1):

You could use two print statements, like this:

```
a = 0
for i in range(0,10):
  if i<1:
    a+= i
    print(a)
  elif i>8:
    a+= i
    print(a)
```